# Using Beautiful Soup to create new_tag with attribute named "name"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've got a block of XML that I need to insert some elements into

```
<importer in="!SRCFILE!" media="movie">
<video-out id="video_2_importer"></video-out>
<audio-out id="audio_2_importer"></audio-out>
</importer>
```

What I need to do is insert a few options into this block so my output looks like this:

```
<importer media="movie" in="!SRCFILE!">
    <video-out id="video_2_importer"></video-out>
    <audio-out id="audio_2_importer"></audio-out>
    <option name="start-time" value="60"></option>
    <option name="end-time" value="120"></option>
</importer>
```

I've successfully used bs4 to find the element and create new tags, but it appears the argument 'name' is a reserved word in bs4.  I've tried the following:

```
in_point = soup.new_tag('option', **{'value':'60','name':'start-time'})
```

But I get the following error

```
TypeError: new_tag() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'
```

If I remove the 'name':'start-time' from my dict, it does properly insert.  If I change 'name' to any other text, it works.  So doing the following results in a proper tag creation.

```
in_point = soup.new_tag('option', **{'value':'60','stuff':'start-time'})
```

I know there is likely something I'm doing wrong syntacticly to get around allowing me to use the attribute 'name', I just have no idea what.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, you can create the instance of the `Tag` this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

in_point = Tag(builder=soup.builder, 
               name='option', 
               attrs={'value':'60','name':'start-time'})
```

which is essentially what `new_tag()` is doing under-the-hood:

```
def new_tag(self, name, namespace=None, nsprefix=None, **attrs):
    """Create a new tag associated with this soup."""
    return Tag(None, self.builder, name, namespace, nsprefix, attrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful Soup uses dictionaries to build tags. You don't need a Tag import to do this. Just create an attribute as you'd create a key: value in a dictionary.
For example: importer['media'] = "movie"